# youtube-dl gave me an error about ssl

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

Following is the error that youtube-dl gave me. Another tool `you-get` gave me a similar error. What should I do to download videos from youtube.

```
[~] youtube-dl -f 137 https://youtu.be/0Ef9GudbxXY
```

> 17:27:23 [youtube] 0Ef9GudbxXY: Downloading webpage ERROR: Unable to
>   download webpage:  (caused by
>   URLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:841)'),))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that there is a problem with the TLS certificate. Typical suspects are, in rough order descending likeliness, according to my experiences working as a youtube-dl developer:

- [Censorship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_of_YouTube) by your country, especially if you are located in or near [China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship_in_China), [Pakistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websites_blocked_in_Pakistan), or other non-democratic countries. You can use a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) or TOR with a bridge to avoid the censorship.
- Censorship by your company, school, or ISP. Again, a VPN (or proxy) can avoid this.
- Local [anti-malware software](https://zakird.com/papers/https_interception.pdf) trying to intercept connections.
- Local malware software trying to intercept connections.
- A proxy server that is now misbehaving. Add `-v` to the command line to see whether one is configured.
- A local configuration problem, i.e. missing certificate store or so. This depends a lot on how you installed youtube-dl.
- A configuration problem on YouTube's side.

In any case, you can avoid certificate checking by passing in `--no-check-certificate`. However, note that this will allow nation states, ISPs, schools/companies, hackers, and other (semi-)malicious parties to log, intercept, and change your video traffic.

Note: The video https://youtu.be/0Ef9GudbxXY is not available in format 137. Simply leave out `-f` to get the best available format.

Comment: @WilliamSong If this (or any other) answer solved your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141962). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading python version 2.7.18 to latest fixed this error.